# Running Chef Client

Tags: json, chef-infra, devops

I have an Application A and I have updated the cookbook which is related to that application from 1.0 to 2.0 in the environment file x.json

Comment: The command is `chef-client`, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you need SSH to the server and run `chef-client` as root (so usually `sudo chef-client`).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time we schedule the chef-client command in CRON jobs to run  in intervals of time. So we don't need to worry about running chef-client command each and every time we change and upload the cookbooks.